# Add a leading zero to date less than 9

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to add a leading zero to date less than 9 in a date comlumn. when i select a single digit date, Share point does not display it with a leading zero. I have selected the Gregorian Calendar. Is there any formula i can use to make it a calculated column and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`=TEXT(Date,"mm/dd/yyyy")` - this will trim off the leading zero from the month

Answer (score 0):

You will have to format the date into a text string using the [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG) in a new Calculated Column

```
=TEXT( Date , "dd/mm/yyyy" )
```

Comment: I know i am being dumb but can please tell me the steps to do it. I am a Shaepoint newbie